# CGMutablePath X and Y should take on its view's bounds

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that is constrained to a top and a bottom such that its height will be dynamic. I then add a layer to add a vertical dashed line.

The following is the code in `extension UIView`:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [4, 3]
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
    CGPoint(x: x, y: 40)])
shapeLayer.path = path
layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

I want the `40` to be dynamic and take on the view's bounds but when I check the value of the bounds it is always `0`.

Comment: Where do you add this function? In your `init` of `UIView`?

Comment: This is added as a function of the `extension UIView` which I then call on my dashedLineView given that `let dashedLineView = UIView()`

Comment: Try calling your `let dashedLineView = UIView(frame: yourDesiredRect)`

Comment: I don't think I should? height should not be constant, and should be based on the layout constraints

Comment: For that, after you've created your `dashedLineView `, you can set constraints on it. And then update your path, when the frame changes.

Comment: I'd update paths in `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `0` bounds, because frame is not set yet. Once you pass in the frame, your first render would be correct. But afterwards, when constraints change the frame, you would need to update your dashed path as well.

You can override your UIView property

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            updatePath()
        }
    }
```

and do the same for bounds

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            updatePath()
        }
    }
```

In your `updatePath()`, you'll first have to remove your previously drawn path or just update it.

Comment: this worked! but I did not have to explicitly set the frame